# Proj4js Projection anomaly between function vs string projection definition

Tags: proj4js

We recently switched our definitions from the first to the second format, because OpenLayers threw exceptions on the first one.

The used definitions:
Old:

```
proj4.defs["EPSG:28992"] = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs";
```

New:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:28992", "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000  +ellps=bessel  +towgs84=565.040,49.910,465.840,-0.40939,0.35971,-1.86849,4.0772 +units=m +no_defs")
```

Strange enough, the latter one does correctly transform points. Our points seem to be misaligned, and not by a specific offset, they seem to be just wrong positioned at all. We think this is due to the `towgs84` property. Question now is,  how is the first format parsed/ handled differently than the secondly? What are the differences? (I am using the same code and newest version of proj4js in both occasions).

Answer (score 2):

I was accidentally loading pro4j twice, once trough potree, and once manually (for openlayers). Turned out one of the two was still on version `2.2.1`...